# In final class derived from base class with virtual destructor, does derived class destructor need “virtual” keyword? Should it have “final” keyword?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a `Base` class with `virtual` destructor and `final` `Derived` inheritor:

```cpp
class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() { 
    // some impl
  }
};

class Derived final : public Base {
public:
  virtual ~Derived() override {
    // some other impl
  }
};
```

I have the following questions:

- Does `~Derived` needs `virtual` specifier?
- Should I mark `~Derived` as `final`?

Comment: Marking the function `override` would make more sense than `virtual`.

Comment: I revised the title to try to make it more helpful to future readers/searchers. Please refine it further if needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `~Derived()` will be a virtual destructor, whether you apply the keyword or not.  That's because the base class destructor is virtual.
2. `~Derived()` will be a final overrider, because it is a member of a class which is marked `final`.  It does not matter whether you use the `final` keyword directly on the destructor or not.

Comment: The second point is interesting from another angle. If one marks the d'tor but not the class, [Clang warns](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sxJ11rhEGW1ySXXy) because it accomplishes the same net result, except roundabout.

Comment: Yes, that was expected, but I didnt know about such inspection in Clang, thanks.